# How to share a library between two identical swfs on the same HTML page?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

I am running two swfs that both use [ASWing](http://www.aswing.org/) UI library, is there a way to load the shared library of ASWing only once ? currently, I am loading the library for each swf file on the same page.

p.s: the two SWFs are identical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know there is not other way to share RSLs apart from loading them again. This shouldn't be an issue for you as the first swf to load it will cache it, as per Adobe's docs:

When multiple applications share a core set of components or classes, clients can download those assets only once as an RSL rather than once for each application. The RSLs are persisted on the client disk so that they do not need to be transferred across the network a second time. The resulting file size for the applications can be reduced. The benefits increase as the number of applications that use the RSL increases.

Comment: oh, that's sad, as I feel that even using the loaded cached library is not lite weight solution .. its a bit heavy on page ..